# Is it possible to remove the 'Delete' and 'Add x' on the 'table' field for Laravel Backpack?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm currently setting up a backpack CRUD for languages/translations, and I'd like the translations to be bulk editable from the language CRUD. I've currently got that working through the update operation like so:

```
    protected function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        $this->setupCreateOperation();
        CRUD::addField([
            'name' => 'translations',
            'label' => 'Translations',
            'type' => 'table',
            'entity_singular' => 'translation',
            'columns' => [
                'key' => 'Key',
                'text' => 'Text'
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

Which looks like this:
[preview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDuEm.png)

The problem I'm running into here is that all the 'keys' should be static (but still displayed), as well as that users shouldn't be able to 'add' translations or remove them. (Translation creation is handled by setting up default translations each time a language is created)

Is it possible to

1. Make it so that the 'key' column is uneditable but still displayed.
2. Remove the 'Add translation' button at the bottom of the table.
3. Remove the 'Delete' trashcan icon at the end of each translation line

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Add these lines to your Controller. You can add it anywhere but I prefer to add in `public function setup()`

```php
$this->crud->denyAccess('delete');
$this->crud->denyAccess('create');
```

However user cannot add Translation but this will not remove the <kbd>+ Add Translation</kbd> button. So to remove that button also,
**remove this line**

```php
use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
```

---

Sources:

1. https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/257
2. https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operation-show

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll give it a try soon

Comment: And about this `1. Make it so that the 'key' column is uneditable but still displayed.` Check out this code and see the `getFieldsData` method  and see how I handle it. https://codeshare.io/yoqlXn